# Conditional Density of an Exponential Given Gamma

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, conditional-probability, density-function, exponential-distribution

Hey Guys i get stuck in this problem which says:

> $(T_n)_{n>1}$ a succession of iid's R.V's of an $\exp(\lambda)$ and let
>   $T=T_1+T_2+\cdots+T_n$

a) Find the law of $T_1$ given $T$

Obviously i know that $T\sim\operatorname{Gamma}(n,\lambda)$, but if i do the classic approach by definition:

$$f_{T_1\mid T}(t)=\frac{f_{T_1,T}(t)}{f_T(t)}$$

But to get the Joint Distribution, also i understand that because of independence all of $f_{T_{i},T}$(t) would be equal.

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems you are not given the sum. You are given the last RV and you are told all RVs are independent. So you seem to be trying to make this problem hard: What you are asking is not what the question asks of you.

Comment: @Michael You’re right, my mistake, I’m gonna edit it

Comment: Ah, if you are given $T$ then you want $$f_{T_1|T}(t|y)=\frac{f_{T_1,T}(t,y)}{f_T(y)}$$ So you need another variable $y$.

Comment: I get it, abuse of notation , but to get i get $f(T_1|T)$ im thinking about a product of convolution of what else?

Comment: Depends on what you are comfortable with. You could define $U=T-T_1$, which is independent of $T_1$, and do a pdf transformation between $(T_1,U)$ and $(T_1,T)$. Or you could differentiate $P[T_1\leq t, T \leq y]$.

Comment: Let $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n T_n$ and $N(t) = \sup\{n>0:S_n\leqslant t\}$. It is known that, conditioned on $\{N(t) = n\}$, the joint distribution of $(T_1,\ldots,T_n)$ is the same as the joint distribution of $(U_{(1)},\ldots,U_{(n)})$, where $U_{(i)}$ is the $i^{\mathrm{th}}$ order statistic of the uniform distribution on $(0,t)$. Can you continue from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
let $X_i \sim E(\lambda)$ and $T=\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i$

so $$P(X_1<a|T=t)=P(\frac{X_1}{T}<\frac{a}{t}|T=t)=P(\frac{X_1}{T}<\frac{a}{t})$$

note $T$ is complete  and sufficient for $\lambda$ and $\frac{X_1}{T}$ does not depend on $\lambda$. so by Basu theorem they are independet.

[Basu's_theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basu%27s_theorem)

And it is easy to find

$$\frac{X_1}{T}=\frac{X_1}{X_1 +X_2 +\cdots +X_n}\sim Beta(1,n-1)$$

Comment: Hey there! I think I got it, I would be a Beta(1,n-1) because all the $f(X_i|Y)$ are the same no?

Comment: You edit it later i post my comment but pretty nice though. thanks

Comment: I hope It will solve the problem.

Comment: I finally realize that is actually the original T distribution (the gamma one) times the beta(1,n-1). But there's a name for ti weird distribution?.