# Conditional Density of an Exponential Given a Sum of Exponential (Gamma)

Tags: conditional-probability, density-function, exponential-distribution, gamma-distribution

I'm wondering about this particular problem [Conditional Density of an Exponential Given Gamma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3582379/conditional-density-of-an-exponential-given-gamma?fbclid=IwAR3_qoUNVwBBgyshNfBKjSUsAUvZObktlc6V8Fp16VNIpk2kqJ_AXpykLgs)

I did not understand the anwser. In fact, we didn't see Basu's theorem in class, and i would like to understand the problem without this theorem. Could someone be help me find another way to solve it?

Thank you very much

Comment: I'd recommend you edit this post by adding some details to explain what it is that you don't understand about the other post. If you don't do this, then this post may be closed. If this post gets closed, then no one will be able to post an answer to it.

Comment: Alright, thank you. I'm new here so I don't know how this all works!

Comment: You also asked this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3605787/321264). Please do not create unnecessary extra posts.